# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #158: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to use `color.xml` file for my button, but it show this error and app crash. It says, it cannot find the `color.xml` file.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/color.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0e00dd
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3783)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3651)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3983)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1021)
  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:115)
  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:5
```

**Here is my button xml:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_buy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/color"
    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
    android:text="@string/buy"/>
```

**This is my color.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/grey" />
    <item android:color="@color/myRedColor"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: add selector file in drawable

Comment: what is `@color/buy`? simply color-code or xml file?

Comment: Do you mean add the color.xml file to folder drawable? I try it, but still get the same error.

Comment: @K.Sopheak I don't see where the color/buy is declared. Your color.xml file does'n contains it.

Comment: @vrundpurohit I edit my post. Actually, it is @color/color. It is the color.xml file.

Comment: move it to drawable folder and use it like `android:background="@drawable/color"`

Comment: and change it names to something else it may be an issue to use the color name.

Comment: @Nepster Wait, let me try first

Comment: It still not work.

Comment: Simply try pasting your color.xml to drawable folder and change android:background="@color/color" to android:background="@drawable/color" . And make sure you have changed it name. And then open file where you have added mdtp_white .And if still error occurs paste your color.xml which contains all colors like mdtp_white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the error. I look strange but it work. First, move the `color.xml` to **drawable folder**. Then update the `color.xml` like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <color android:color="@color/grey"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/myRedColor"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create color.xml file in Drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/myRedColor" />
</selector>
```

Use color.xml as background in button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_buy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    // here
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
    android:text="@string/buy"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`android:background` attribute requires a `drawable` resource. All you need to do is moving your `color.xml` file to `drawable` folder.

Comment: @K.Sopheak Please update  your code first. I still see the word "buy"

Comment: @K.Sopheak I still see "/color/color.xml". You need to move color.xml file to folder drawable. And for your Button use this line: `android:background="@drawable/color"`

Answer (score 1):

Paste your color.xml file in drawble folder and add color.xml as backgrouned to your button like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_buy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
    android:text="@string/buy"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

put your **color.xml** file in `drawable`

make changes in **drawable\color.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/grey" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/myRedColor"/>
</selector>
```

**button xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_buy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
    android:text="@string/buy"/>
```